# Skip odd number of preceding symbols when searching

Tags: node.js, regex

**Question**

Using RegEx, how to find index of the first `'` that's not preceded by odd number of `\`?

---

**Details**

In my code, I can detect beginning of a PostgreSQL string, which starts with `'`, and I need a RegEx to find valid ending in the string that follows, with the matching `'`, or to tell me when there is no valid closure, i.e. string is invalid.

The problem I'm having is how to skip the special case when `'` is preceded by an odd number of `\`, i.e. the following cases are to be skipped: `\'`, `\\\'`, `\\\\\'`, etc.

Is it possible to skip such special cases in RegEx and either give me the closure index, or -1, if it does not exist?

Comment: Mind sharing what you're hoping to do here?  It seems like you're trying to parse SQL using Javascript.  Is this the case?

Comment: @ctt, yes, but specifically for an SQL string. I need to find a valid end of an SQL string, if it exists. In truth, I am trying to fix a bug [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-minify/issues/2), with the help of RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a valid regex to match only the first `'` preceded by an even number of `\`:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(?!\\)\'
```

But I do not know if negative lookahead/lookbehind are supported.
I am essentially saying: just match `\\` (not escaped) that are before or after other `\`.

---

EDIT: @revo made me notice the last part is redundant, the correct regex is:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*'
```

Comment: Why do you have `(?!=\\)`? Did you mean `(?!\\)`?

Comment: Oops. Thank you @revo.

Comment: No problem. BTW it is redundant. You could safely remove it.